# Find duplicate values in a column A and compare dates in column B

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I got a data frame like this:

```
Source: | Date:
A         2015-12-03
A         2015-11-01
B         2015-12-01
A         2015-10-04
C         2015-11-01
C         2015-11-12
```

I wish to create a new data frame were there is only one instance per unique Source value with the earliest Date value. Like so:

```
Source: | Date:
A         2015-10-04
B         2015-12-01
C         2015-11-01
```

It is simple enough to get unique source values, but I find it hard to come up with a solution to check if Source is a duplicate and if so save the earliest Date.

Anyone got a simple way for solving this?

Comment: Without using packages I would do `df <- df[order(as.Date(df$Date)), ] ; df[!duplicated(df$Source),]`. Using packages I would go with `library(data.table) ; unique(setDT(df)[order(as.Date(Date))], by = "Source")`

Comment: dplyr: `df %>% group_by(Source) %>% summarise(Date = min(Date))`

Comment: Worked as a charm!